# Group by not working correctly for a range of dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
created_date  | id | status | completed_date
2019-03-20    | 1  | Open   | 
2019-03-20    | 2  | Open   | 
2019-03-19    | 3  | Comp   | 2019-03-21
2019-03-21    | 4  | Comp   | 2019-03-22
2019-03-22    | 5  | Comp   | 2019-03-22
2019-03-18    | 6  | Open   |
```

I want to find count of all the `ID`s that were created before `'2019-03-21'` and had a status of `'Open'` OR they were created before `'2019-03-21'` and even had a `'Comp'` status but they were completed after `'2019-03-21'`.

Below is the query I have:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CREATED AS DATE),
    COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM testtable
WHERE
    (CAST(CREATED AS DATE) <= '2019-03-21' AND status = 'Open')
    OR (
        CAST(CREATED AS DATE) <= '2019-03-21' AND status='Comp' 
        AND CAST(COMPLETED AS DATE) > '2019-03-21' 
    )
```

It gives the correct result. i.e., on 21st, 4 IDs were open. But now I want this information for the last 4 days. How do I modify this query to do that??

The output should be:

```
created_date | count(ID)
2019-03-21   | 4
2019-03-20   | 4
2019-03-19   | 2
2019-03-18   | 1
```

Please help!!

Comment: Your sample results have totals that sum to 11, but there are only  six rows in your original data.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works correctly with your sample data. It generates a list of dates using the distinct values that can be found in column `created_date`, and then `LEFT JOIN`s it with the table. The `JOIN` conditions carry the logic your described. It seems to me like you do not need to check the `status` of the records, since, apparently, any record that has a non-`NULL` `completed_date` is in status `Comp`.

```
SELECT 
    dt.created_date,
    COUNT(t.id)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT created_date FROM mytable) dt
    LEFT JOIN mytable t
        ON t.created_date <= dt.created_date 
        AND (t.completed_date IS NULL OR t.completed_date > dt.created_date)
GROUP BY dt.created_date
```

This **[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFKcm1EpnbHn1iQFbjsGnr/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| created_date | COUNT(t.id) |
| ------------ | ----------- |
| 2019-03-18   | 1           |
| 2019-03-19   | 2           |
| 2019-03-20   | 4           |
| 2019-03-21   | 4           |
| 2019-03-22   | 3           |
```